# get value from ckeditor for upload to database using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to get value from ckeditor for upload to database using ajax and jquery

my code is

```
$("#signup_asso").on('submit', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"associate_action.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:new FormData(this),
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try replacing the line "data:new FormData(this)," with "data:CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditorid'].getData(),"

Comment: Thanks.. It works..

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the line

```
"data:new FormData(this),"
```

with

```
"data:CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditorid'].getData(),"
```